# Why does my React Native FlatList keyExtractor return undefined?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

I have written a function to get the key of an item in Firebase Realtime Database.
Function:

```
getKey = (index) => {
    offersRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      const key = Object.keys(data)[index]
      console.log('the key is ' + key)
      return key
    })
  }
```

keyExtractor in FlatList:

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => this.getKey(index), console.log(this.keyExtractor)}
```

This function is called in the keyExtractor of my FlatList. However, while the console.log in getKey returns the correct value, the keyExtractor is undefined. I don't understand this - aren't the two supposed to return exactly the same result?
[image: react]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function was not actually returning key. While the snapshot returned key, the function itself was actually not returning anything. I fixed this by changing the code to

```
getKey = (index) => {
    let key = 0;
      offersRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        let data = snapshot.val();
        key = Object.keys(data)[index]
      })
      return key
  }
```